# How to select number integers from a string sequence wise from left to right in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers, sequence

I have an input element in which users are to enter the price of the product.

```
<input size=10 type="text" id="prd_price" title="prd_price" name="prd_price">
```

My users can enter the Currency Symbols aswell as other things and I am not allowed to stop them from doing this. I have to just select the numbers and form the value of the price from their input string, whether they enter currency symbols in front or after the price or also make the input string comma formatted like 1,000.00.

Can anyone help me to find if their is a javascript function from which I can scoop up the number integers from the input string sequentially from left to right?

Comment: is there any reason not to use the `type=number` html5 input that only allows numbers?

Comment: you can loop through the characters for the input and check c <= '9' && c>='0', and collect the digits.

Comment: @finalfreq The reason is that I am to allow users to see the currency symbol with the price, and if they type the currency symbol for me, I need to just select the numbers from it.

Comment: Do you want the number to be _correct_, though? With an input of `1a000` do you expect that to be `1` or `1000` or nothing? What if the input is formatted with thousand separators, e.g., `1,000` - is that `1000`? What if the user uses non-English separators, e.g., `1 000,00` for what would otherwise be expressed as `1000.00`? What if a user enters `1K` for a thousand?

Comment: @vlaz if the user enters 1a000 I would like javascript to change it to 1000 for me. And for 1,000.00 i would also like javascript to change this to 1000 for me.

Comment: `scoop up the number integers from the input string sequentially from left to right?` Isn't that description right to left?

Comment: @Xotic750 in english numerical values are always written from left to right. So it makes sense to try to establish context like this. Otherwise one would entirely make the number upside down.

Comment: I misread a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's easy

```
alert(new Number("blah 12345,;(,84".match(/(?:\d+|\.)/g).join("")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot KOLANICH. This is perfect solution for me.